# How to pass @ as a ftp password in php

Tags: ftp, file-get-contents

I have to use @ in a password string for ftp

```
$file = "ftp://username:password@xyz.com/public_html/filename";
```

when i use password 'xyz@!@#' it does not work because @ is used by ftp as a separator. But many user use special character specially @.

Pls help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using UrlEncoding. I think the encoder for "@" is "%40" (without the double-quotes)